# how to set Latin Modern Mono Proportional in Xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontspec, lmodern

I am using `xelatex` and `fontspec`:

I tried something like:

```
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text, CharacterWidth=Proportional]{Latin Modern Mono}
```

but this does not exist (?).

How can I set the mono font to Latin Modern Mono Proportional which exists in the Latin Modern font?

Comment: If you use pdfLaTeX, it is also easy ;).

Comment: @cfr How, exactly?

Comment: @DavidMoles Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the font by its name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Prop}

\newfontfamily{\monott}{Latin Modern Mono} % for testing

\begin{document}

abcim \texttt{abcim} abcim

abcim {\monott abcim} abcim

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the `\texttt` line prints proportional typewriter type.

Comment: where can we find the font names used for fontspec?

Comment: @Gabriel If you installed the font system wide, the standard OS tool should be able to provide the information.

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer: I am the author of the package discussed below.

This does not answer the question as such. Rather, it answers a related question which is how the same thing may be done using pdfLaTeX or, indeed, LaTeX.

I assume this is legitimate since when people ask how to use a font, even if they specifically say they can't use Xe/LuaTeX, enthusiasts routinely answer using those engines in order to show how much greener the grass is on the other side.

Nonetheless, I would not be posting this if [David Moles hadn't followed up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306893/how-to-set-latin-modern-mono-proportional-in-xelatex?noredirect=1#comment772023_306893) [a comment I made](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306893/how-to-set-latin-modern-mono-proportional-in-xelatex?noredirect=1#comment744651_306893) to ask [*how* to do this easily with pdfTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306893/how-to-set-latin-modern-mono-proportional-in-xelatex?noredirect=1#comment772023_306893). I don't claim that the grass is greener on the other side in this case, but only that it is equally green or as green as anybody could reasonably want, additional greenness being entirely superfluous to requirements.

---

There are two core cases:

1. you want to set variable width as the default typewriter family for the document, with the option of switching to monowidth when required;
2. you want monowidth as the default, with the option to switch to variable width.

For the first,

```
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
```

will do this. Then typewriter text will use variable width by default.

```
{\tmstyle
  ...
}
```

will switch to monowidth, while

```
\texttm{...}
```

will typeset its argument in monowidth.

For the second case, use

```
\usepackage[tt=monowidth]{cfr-lm}
```

and then

```
{\tvstyle
  ...
}
```

and

```
\texttv{...}
```

for variable width.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[tt=monowidth]{cfr-lm}% monowidth as default
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}
\texttt{This typewriter text is variable width by default.}

{\tmstyle
This typewriter text is now monowidth.
This could also be set as the document's default using the relevant package option.
Then you'd use \verb|\tvstyle| to switch to variable width.}

\texttm{This typewriter text is also monowidth.}

\texttt{If the default was monowidth \textbackslash texttv\{\dots\} would produce variable width text like this.}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: equally green grass]

---

`cfr-lm` aims to provide access to

- all fonts in the Latin Modern family provided that the fonts themselves are among those provided in type1 format;
- all font features supported by those fonts, insofar as this is practicable and the features make sense in pdfTeX;
- convenient access to the various fonts and features via package options and/or an extended set of font switches and font text commands;
- support the use of a variety of different fonts and features within the same document.

Note that the final point does not mean it is typographically wise to make use of this feature to excess. It just means that if you want to ignore the ancient wisdom of the typographic sages and use 4 different styles of numerals, 2 different typewriter styles, 2 different kinds of italic, 2 different styles of sans, italic small-caps, multiple weights/widths, Dunhill etc. etc., then there is nothing technically to prevent your doing so.

[image: italic sc + upright italic]

[image: hanging figures]

[image: lining figures]

[image: Dunhill]

[image: variable weights]

[image: variable weights & widths]